# Submit 2 forms on single button click and pass response of 1st form to 2nd form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, dropzone

I am trying to submit 2 form on a single click. 1 form contains only text boxes and 2nd form have dropzone images. now when 1st form submit it should returns the and i need to pass that id 2nd form when submit so the images will save against that id in database. textboxes form is submitted by don't know how to get id and problem is saving the images in 2nd form

HTML Form

```
         <div class="modal-body p0">
            <div id="" >
               <div class="max-wid">
                  <div class="pl-3 pr-3 mb-5 p0">
                     <div class="">
                        <div class=" f-column in">
                           <div class="">
                              <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-border-producttab">
                                 <li class="nav-item ">
                                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#add_new_products2">Add New Product</a>
                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                           </div>
                           <div class="">
                              <div >
                                 <div class=" mt-3">
                                    <div class="tab-content model-hit">
                                       <div id="add_new_products2" class="container tab-pane active">
                                          <br>
                                          <div class=" row">
                                             <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 mrg_modal_produt">
                                                   <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 label_modal_product">
                                                      Product Documents
                                                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                                      <div class="gry f-13">(Specs, CHPS Certificate, Product Data Sheet)</div>
                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <?php echo Form::open(array('route' => 'architecture-product-file-save', 'files' => true, 'method' => 'PUT', 'id' => 'product-file-form', 'class' => 'dropzone')); ?>
                                                   <div id="preview-template" style="display: none;">
                                                      <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
                                                         <div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></div>

                                                         <div class="dz-file-type">
                                                            <br />
                                                            <select name="file_type" class="dz-file-type-select">
                                                               <option value="">Select File Type</option>
                                                               <option value="datasheet_file">Datasheet</option>
                                                               <option value="cad_file">CAD file</option>
                                                               <option value="bim_file">BIM file</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                         </div>
                                                      </div>
                                                   </div>
                                                   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save" id="save-product-files-submit" style="display:none;">
                                                </form>
                                             </div>

                                             <?php echo Form::open(array('route' => 'architecture-product-save', 'files' => true, 'id' => 'product-form')) ?>
                                             <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="col-sm-12 p-0 mrg_modal_produt">
                                                   <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control input_product_modal" value="Product Name">
                                                   <input name="" type="text" class="form-control input_product_modal" value="Manufacturer Name">
                                                   <select name="division" id="division" class="form-control input_product_modal">
                                                      <option>MasterFormat Division</option>
                                                      @foreach ($division_list as $item)
                                                   <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->name}}</option>
                                                      @endforeach
                                                   </select>
                                                   <select name="section" id="section" class="form-control input_product_modal">

                                                   </select>
                                                   <textarea name="" class="form-control input_product_modal" cols="" rows="">Product Description (copy and paste from manufactures information)</textarea>
                                                   <input name="" type="text" class="form-control input_product_modal" value="LEED data">
                                                   <input name="website" type="text" class="form-control input_product_modal" value="Link to product website">
                                                   <input name="video_file" type="text" class="form-control input_product_modal" value="Link to Product Video (YouTube or Vimeo)">
                                                   <input name="bim_file_url" type="text" class="form-control input_product_modal" value="Link to BIM file">
                                                   <input name="" type="text" class="form-control input_product_modal" value="Link to AIA learning unit course">
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save" id="save-product-form-submit" style="display:none;">
                                          </form>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn-bg2" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <input type="button" class="btn-bg1"  id="save-product-form" value="Add to Project">
         </div>
      </div>
```

jsvascript

```
<script>
      Dropzone.options.productFileForm = {
              dictDefaultMessage: 'Drag and Drop (tap to search for a file)',
              autoProcessQueue: false,
              previewTemplate: document.getElementById('preview-template').innerHTML,
              addRemoveLinks: true,
              init: function() {
                  var myDropzone = this;

                  $('#save-product-form').click(function (){
                      $('#save-product-form-submit').click();
                      $('#save-product-files-submit').click();
                  });
}
}

      </script>
```

this route works fine `architecture-product-save` but don't know how to get id from the controller and pass to `architecture-product-file-save`

Controller

```
public function ArchitectureProductSave(Request $request){

    $architecture = Manufacturer::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get()->first();

    $lastRecordSeq = DB::table('products')
                                ->where('manufacturer_id',$architecture->id)
                                ->where('section_id',Input::get('section_id'))
                                ->orderBy('sequence_id','desc')
                                ->first();
    if(!empty($lastRecordSeq))
    {
        $sequenceId = $lastRecordSeq->sequence_id;
        $sequenceId = $sequenceId + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $sequenceId = 1;
    }

    $product = new Product;
        $product->name = Input::get('name');
        $product->description = Input::get('description');
        $product->manufacturer_id = $architecture->id;
        $product->division_id = Input::get('division');
        $product->section_id = Input::get('section');
        $product->sequence_id = $sequenceId;
        $productVideoFile = Input::get('video_file');
        $productVideFileArr = explode('&', $productVideoFile);
        if(empty($productVideFileArr)){
            $product->video_file = Input::get('video_file');
        }else{
            $product->video_file = $productVideFileArr[0];
        }

        $product->cad_file_url = Input::get('cad_file_url');
        $product->bim_file_url = Input::get('bim_file_url');              
        $product->website = Input::get('website');

        if ($product->save())
    {
            $msg = $product->id;
            return response()->json([
                'message' => $msg
                    ], 200);
        }
    }

public function ArchitectProductFileUpdate($id, Request $request) {
dd($request)}
```

Errors: 
Argument 2 passed to App\Modules\Manufacturer\Controllers\ProjectController::ArchitectProductFileUpdate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given

Comment: Does the first function save your input in your database, even if you get this exception?

Comment: yes 1st function saves the data as expected and returns the latest inserted id @zlatangoralija

Comment: Okay, I can't understand why do you need two separate forms, I feel like this could all be done in one form.

Comment: yes it can be done in one form but because i am using dropzone plugin styling  is an issue for me so i created a separate form for images dropzone automatic attach with the form so when data of 1st form is added it gets the id i need to pass the id in 2nd form conatains images so i an insert images against that id @zlatangoralija

Comment: As described this sounds like a broken design

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, first you submit first form which insert data into DB and generate ID and you need this ID in second form submission. If this is, then you can do like this:

1. after submission of first form from ajax, you need to return ID in response. Then store it in second form html. LIKE:

input type="hidden" id="ffid" name="first_form_id" value="">

script code:

```
$("#ffid").val(response.ID)// response.ID is response from first form submission.
```

2. Now you just need to get and send this ID in your second form.

I hope this idea will help you.

/*************EDIT V1 *******************/

```
$('#save-product-form').click(function (){
$('#save-product-form-submit').click();
 $('#save-product-form-submit').click(function(response){
    alert(response);//let see id is coming or not

 }); 
 $('#save-product-files-submit').click(); 
})


</script>
```

Comment: `$('#save-product-form').click(function (){
                      $('#save-product-form-submit').click();
                      $('#save-product-files-submit').click();
                  })` here is the code how can i get response on click form is submitted how to get the response that u mentioned

Comment: I have again edited my answer, can you give one more try.

Comment: it redirects to the controller method and returns the id but i don't want it to redirect save data like ajax and return the id on same page